# How to merge/copy different rows into one conditionally [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, lag

I have a large data frame with names and a "classifying" variable named **sequence**. **sequence** tells about the position regarding the other rows. It has two values: *first* and *additional*.
The problem is that the distribution of these values is not uniform, i.e., there's not an *additional* per every *first*, and every *letters* value is unique.
The data frame looks like this (simplified version):

```
letters <- sample(LETTERS, 20)
sequence <- c("first","additional","first","first","first","first","first","additional","additional","additional","first","first","additional","first","additional","additional","first","additional","first","first")
df <- data.drame(sequence, letters)
```

Now, what I want to do is take every *additional* value in **letters** and paste it into its corresponding *first* value in **letters**.
So, for example, the second (row) value in the **letters** column would be pasted into the first, since it's the corresponding *additional*. Further, the eigth, ninth and tenth values in **letters** should be pasted inside (next to) the seventh value of **letters** (e.g., *first*; *additional*; *additional*; *additional*).

I've tried the following with the obvious limitation that it only looks to the immediate next value,

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- df %>% mutate(letters_ok = if_else(sequence == "additional",
                                            paste(letters, lag(letters), sep = "; "), letters))
```

highlighting my problem: How do I manage to lag conditionally on the values in **sequence**, so that I can paste the values in **letters** according to the *first* or *additional* classification?

Since every **letters** value is unique and it's tied to a specific **sequence** value, I didn't use group_by. Evry other solution eludes my current knowledge of string/character wrangling, so I would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach.. I slightly alterend your sample data, since `letters` is not a very convenient column name. Also, added `set.seed(123)` for reproductional purposes.

**sample data**

```
set.seed(123)
letter <- sample(LETTERS, 20)
sequence <- c("first","additional","first","first","first","first","first","additional","additional","additional","first","first","additional","first","additional","additional","first","additional","first","first")
df <- data.frame(sequence, letter)

#      sequence letter
# 1       first      O
# 2  additional      S
# 3       first      N
# 4       first      C
# 5       first      J
# 6       first      R
# 7       first      K
# 8  additional      E
# 9  additional      X
# 10 additional      Y
# 11      first      W
# 12      first      T
# 13 additional      I
# 14      first      L
# 15 additional      U
# 16 additional      M
# 17      first      P
# 18 additional      H
# 19      first      B
# 20      first      G
```

**code**

```
library( data.table )
#convert to data.table format
setDT(df)
#add id-column
df[, id := .I ]
#perform rolling join
temp <- df[ sequence == "first", ][ df[ sequence == "additional", ], 
                                    .( x.letter, i.letter, i.id, x.id), 
                                    on = .(id), 
                                    roll = Inf ]
#summarise
temp <- temp[, paste0( `i.letter`, collapse = ";" ), by = .(x.id) ]
#join, drop id column
df[sequence == "first", ][ temp, letter := paste( letter, i.V1, sep = ";"), on = .(id = `x.id`) ][, id := NULL]
```

**output**

```
#    sequence  letter
# 1:    first     O;S
# 2:    first       N
# 3:    first       C
# 4:    first       J
# 5:    first       R
# 6:    first K;E;X;Y
# 7:    first       W
# 8:    first     T;I
# 9:    first   L;U;M
#10:    first     P;H
#11:    first       B
#12:    first       G
```